# Referencing environment variables *in* /etc/environment?

Tags: configuration, environment-variables

I recently discovered `/etc/environment`, which seems a more standard way to setup simple environment variables than scripts, but I was wondering if there was a way to back-reference environment variables in the /etc/environment file.

That is, I have this:

```
JAVA_HOME="/tools/java"
GRAILS_HOME="/tools/grails"
GROOVY_HOME="/tools/groovy"
GRADLE_HOME="/tools/gradle"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

If I try to add `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to the PATH definition, however, I get $JAVA_HOME/bin, and not the interpolated variable. To remedy this, I'm creating environment.sh in profile.d to add the `/bin` entries to the path, but this seems sloppy and disorganized.

Is there a way to backreference the environment variables in /etc/environment?

Answer (score 14):

The `/etc/environment` file is read by the [`pam_env` PAM module](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/pam_env.8.html). It only supports simple key-value pairs, with no substitution on the right-hand side.

If you want to build the value with substitutions or other shell expansions, you need to go through a shell. `/etc/profile` (or a file in `/etc/profile.d`) is the right place for these. This is the traditional place (`/etc/environment` is a relatively recent innovation, in the history of unix systems), and there's certainly nothing sloppy about using it. The main benefit of `/etc/environment` is that it allows environment variables to be set even with login methods that do not involve a shell or for users who use a non-Bourne shell, but these are not common in practice.

Comment: Without substitution, you end up with lots of redundancies in `/etc/environment`, I resorted to `/etc/profile`, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The Ubuntu documentation makes this seem impossible.  BUT, there is an answer.

**ANSWER**: Create persistent, system wide environment variables in `/etc/.bashrc`

```
JAVA_HOME="/tools/java"
...
PATH="$JAVA_HOME:$PATH"
```

**Details:**
Here are some more details from the [Environment Variables documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).
The official recommendation is to use `/etc/environment`, as you have tried.  The problem is this file is not a script file.  In other words, you cannot use variables in variable declarations.

The documentation continues with 2 other "Not Recommended" files
`/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

`/etc/profile` "does little more than invoke the /etc/bash.bashrc file".  So instead choose

`/etc/bash.bashrc` because "Ubuntu is configured by default to execute this file whenever a user enters a shell or the desktop environment."

Comment: I have updated [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) in consultation with some Ubuntu developers, so those "not recommended" statements are not there any longer.

Comment: "whenever a user enters a shell". what should I do when there is no user to enter a shell? I need environment variables for my automated users that run software on startup. For example, I have 6 lines of proxy configuration alone. What should I do with it?