# "Pointers" with $ Syntax in /etc/environment

Tags: environment-variables, paths, etc

Is it valid to have "pointers" in /etc/environment using $FOO syntax?  Right now my /etc/environment looks like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
MAVEN_HOME=/usr/bin/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.4
M2_HOME=$MAVEN_HOME
M2=$MAVEN_HOME/bin
PATH=/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$MAVEN_HOME/bin
```

I'm not getting the results that I'm expecting though:

```
~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
~$ echo $MAVEN_HOME
/usr/bin/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.4
~$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin/bin:/usr/games:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$MAVEN_HOME/bin
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I didn't find much documentation on `/etc/environment`, but the reason things don't work the way you expect is that it's "not a script file", and thus is not processed by the shell, so referencing a previously-defined variable doesn't work. This explains the behaviour you're seeing.

You're better off defining these kinds of environment variables in your home, in `.profile` or `.bashrc`, or if you need them for all users, in `/etc/profile.d` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

There's some pretty extensive documentation on setting environment variables [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables), and it points to either `.profile` or `.bashrc` as the preferred place to put this stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  From the post that you cited though:

"Environment variable settings that affect the system as a whole (rather then just a particular user) should not be placed in any of the many system-level scripts that get executed when the system or the desktop session are loaded, but into /etc/environment - This file is specifically meant for system-wide environment variable settings. It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line. Specifically, this file stores the system-wide locale and path settings."

Is that guidance incorrect?

Comment: I'd say it's correct, however you'd lose the ability to reference a variable inside a definition, so you'd have to spell out the full JAVA_HOME and MAVEN_HOME in the PATH variable definition. If you want that, *and* you also want this to be available for all users, I'd say `/etc/profile.d` would be the place to put it, as it's designed so you can drop a separate file with your variables, thus you're not even modifying existing config files, so your changes should survive through upgrades.

Comment: Thanks, will either update the paths to the full/literal paths or will use one of those alternate files.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: My system doesn't have the file `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Has this file been moved somewhere else for ubuntu or is the only rc file loaded in bash on ubuntu the `~/.bashrc`?

Answer (score 4):

The canonical source for the information you seek (at least for flavours of Debian that use SystemD; and derivatives thereof, such as modern versions of Ubuntu) is [`environment.d(5)`](https://manpages.debian.org/experimental/systemd/environment.d.5.en.html#CONFIGURATION_FORMAT) (some formatting in this excerpt has been changed at my discretion for clarity):

> ## Configuration format
>
> The configuration files contain a list of `KEY=VALUE` environment variable assignments, separated by newlines. The right-hand side of these assignments may reference previously defined environment variables, using the `${OTHER_KEY}` and `$OTHER_KEY` format. It is also possible to use `${FOO:-DEFAULT_VALUE}` to expand in the same way as `${FOO}` unless the expansion would be empty, in which case it expands to `DEFAULT_VALUE`, and use `${FOO:+ALTERNATE_VALUE}` to expand to `ALTERNATE_VALUE` as long as `${FOO}` would have expanded to a non-empty value. No other elements of shell syntax are supported.
>
> Each `KEY` must be a valid variable name. Empty lines and lines beginning with the comment character `#` are ignored.
>
> ### Example
>
> #### Example 1. Setup environment to allow access to a program installed in `/opt/foo`
>
> > **`/etc/environment.d/60-foo.conf` :–**
> >
> > ```
> > FOO_DEBUG=force-software-gl,log-verbose
> > PATH=/opt/foo/bin:$PATH
> > LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/foo/lib${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
> > XDG_DATA_DIRS=/opt/foo/share:${XDG_DATA_DIRS:-/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/}
> > ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pointers in `/etc/environment` but have to use a different syntax:

try:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
MAVEN_HOME=/usr/bin/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.4
M2_HOME=${MAVEN_HOME}
M2=${MAVEN_HOME}/bin
PATH="/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${MAVEN_HOME}/bin"
```

Use the curly braces `{}` around the variable names when referring to another variable assignment. So, instead of `$JAVA_HOME`, use `${JAVA_HOME}`. It also seems to be necessary to have quotation marks around the value of a variable in which you have pointer to other variables:

so `PATH="... ${SOME_VAR} ..."`

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't seem to work for me.  I get the literal ${FOO} in the path.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, this does not work.

Comment: /etc/environment is simply "read" or "loaded" but is never run as a script. It will only work for assignment. It won't work if you try to do script like things, for eg. `M2_HOME=${MAVEN_HOME}` and `M2=${MAVEN_HOME}/bin`

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu documentation makes this seem impossible.  BUT, there is an answer.

**ANSWER**: Create persistent, system wide environment variables in `/etc/bash.bashrc`

```
JAVA_HOME="/tools/java"
...
PATH="$JAVA_HOME:$PATH"
```

**Details:**
I posted a lengthier answer on this [AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78856/referencing-environment-variables-in-etc-environment/385036#385036)