# Editing MANPATH from /etc/environment

Tags: environment-variables, etc, environment

Having installed TeX Live on my system (by downloading and running the script from TUG's website: http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html), I tried editing the `MANPATH` variable by adding the following line in my `/etc/environment`:

```
MANPATH=$MANPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/doc/man
```

(There was no `MANPATH` entry previously)

However, setting the `MANPATH` here seems to be overriding the `/etc/manpath.config` file, and thus the system manual pages are no longer found. Whereas, if I use `export` in my `.bashrc`, `mandb` **prepends** the content of `manpath.config` to the exported value.

What is wrong with this syntax? After all, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables does say that `/etc/environment` is the place for setting system-wide environment variables

The same issue for `INFOPATH`

Comment: A previous question's answers suggest that variable interpolations like `$MANPATH` are not supported in `/etc/environment`: http://askubuntu.com/questions/150789/difference-between-bash-bashrc-and-etc-environment-file . I think you would need to extend `/etc/manpath.config` itself with your customizations instead of using `/etc/environment`.

Comment: @Paul So is `manpath.config` the only way to go for achieving global persistence (WITHOUT opening the terminal once)?

Comment: Actually, do you really need a custom installation of texlive in `/usr/local` in the first place? If you install it using Software Center (or `sudo apt-get`) instead, then the man pages would go into the default system path and the question of how to update `MANPATH` would be moot.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this. `sudo apt-get` is apparently choosing `/usr/local` as the default installation directory!

Comment: Sounds like you may be installing from somebody's PPA. On my system, `dpkg -L texlive texlive-base` only lists things in `/etc`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/share`, etc., not `/usr/local`. Take a look at your software sources: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them

Comment: I just downloaded and ran the script from TUG's website: http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9121/discussion-between-paul-and-chatterjee)

Comment: Could you also add the part on `MANPATH` not supporting variable interpolation

Comment: OK sure, why not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A previous question's answers suggest that variable interpolations like `$MANPATH` are not supported in /etc/environment: [difference between bash.bashrc and /etc/environment file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150789/difference-between-bash-bashrc-and-etc-environment-file) . I think you would need to extend `/etc/manpath.config` itself with your customizations instead of using `/etc/environment`.

However, you probably don't need a custom installation of texlive in `/usr/local` in the first place. If you install it using Software Center (or `sudo apt-get`) instead, then the man pages would go into the default system path and the question of how to update `MANPATH` would be moot.