# gdm/lightdm: can't login, but startx works

Tags: 14.04, xorg, login, gdm

I just ran `apt dist-upgrade`. I had ubuntu 14.04. Things went smoothly, but after reboot I can't get past the login screen. I tried both GDM and lightDM, but running `startx` from the terminal works.

---

The only strange things I noticed are:

1. if I try to reinstall the video driver, I get:

   ```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
   or been moved out of Incoming.
   The following information may help to resolve the situation:

   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    xserver-xorg-video-ati : Depends: xorg-video-abi-15
                             Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.14.99.902)
                             Depends: xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl but it is not going to be installed
   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
   ```

   But libcheese is the latest version:

   ```
   dpkg -l | grep libcheese
   ii  libcheese-gtk23:amd64   3.10.2-0ubuntu2   amd64 
   ii  libcheese7:amd64        3.10.2-0ubuntu2   amd64
   ```
2. `uname -a` gives me `3.19.0-49-generic #55~14.04.1-Ubuntu`, while the welcome screen states `Ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS`. Why 3 and 1 ??
3. on boot, I get the following errors:

   ```
    compaudit:105: command not found: getent
    compdump:135: command not found: mv
   ```

   but my PATH seems correct:

   ```
    /home/shitsu/perl5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
   ```

   The same types of errors are present in the `.xsession-errors` file:

   ```
   /usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 24: mktemp: command not found
   /usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 29: : No such file or directory
   /usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 33: cat: command not found
   /usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 34: truncate: command not found
   /usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 29: : No such file or directory
   /usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 33: cat: command not found
   /usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 34: truncate: command not found
   /usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 106: ls: command not found
   /usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 117: exec: gnome-session: not found
   ```

   My `/etc/environment` file is:

   ```
   PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
   PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"
   ```

Please, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, silly of me.

The problem was my `/etc/environment` file. From [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150789/difference-between-bash-bashrc-and-etc-environment-file), I learned that the 2nd line:

```
PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"
```

was literally interpreted: **the `$PATH` variable is not expanded** (as it usually is in a `.bashrc` file).

Using `startx`, I had my session opened, so the PATH set in the `.zshrc` masked the problem.

But I still haven^t figured out the apt dependencies problem though.