# Can't login through GUI 16.04

Tags: 16.04, login, lightdm, paths

I can't login through GUI on Ubuntu version 16.04. This problem occurred after installing JDK 8 and Scala/SBT (if I remember correctly, it was needed to declare paths for Java or something).

I have already tried the 3 usual fixes for this problem and I've also tried editing / looking for possible syntax errors on files like .profile (I can't really get my head around how all these files interact with each others, I'm really new to Linux).

This is text from .xsession-errors:

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 24: mktemp: command not found
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 29: : No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 33: cat: command not found
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 34: truncate: command not found 
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 29: : No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 33: cat: command not found
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 34: truncate: command not found
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 106: ls: command not found
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 117: exec: gnome-session: not found
```

Also, I'm really sorry for the lack of information provided here since I don't really know what should I provide here.

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/731272/gdm-lightdm-cant-login-but-startx-works or https://askubuntu.com/questions/912573/ubuntu-login-loop-lightdm-session-errors or https://askubuntu.com/questions/463213/exec-gnome-session-not-found-when-logging-in-using-lightdm Plus I'd advice to include what you did for this: "This problem occurred after installing JDK 8 and Scala/SBT (if I remember correctly, it was needed to declare paths for Java or something)."

Comment: Can you login in another tty, i.e. Ctrl+Alt+F1, and run `history` to check the last used commands? It may help to refresh your memory

Comment: Try installing gdm.

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what your problem here is: Your PATH is broken.

From your question:

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 24: mktemp: command not found
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 29: : No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 33: cat: command not found
```

Have you modified your PATH variable settings?

And if so, how did you set/modify the PATH variable?

To confirm, log on to a virtual console (CTRL,ALT,F1 key sequence), enter your logon details and then run:

printenv PATH

See what you get. If its' broken, undo any changes you made to configuration files such as `/etc/environment` and entries under `/etc/profile` , and confirm if this fixes the issue you're experiencing.