# Setting PATH variable in /etc/environment vs .profile

Tags: environment-variables, paths

Where is the preferred place to set the `PATH` envvar?

`~/.profile` or `/etc/environment`?

What is the case when `PATH` is set in both places?
Is the end result a concatenation of both values set in those two places?

Comment: The last assignment to PATH prevails, of course. Most scripts set it explicitly at the beginning of the script.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

**Summary:**

- If you want to add a path (e.g. `/your/additional/path`) to your `PATH` variable for your current user only and not for all users of your computer, you normally put it at the end of `~/.profile` like in one of those two examples:

  ```
  PATH="/your/additional/path:$PATH"
  PATH="$PATH:/your/additional/path"
  ```

  Note that the path priorities are descending from left to right, so the first path has the highest priority. If you add your path on the left of `$PATH`, it will have the highest priority and executables in that location will override all others. If you add your path on the right, it will have the lowest priority and executables from the other locations will be preferred.
- However, if you need to set that environment variable for all users, I would still not recommend touching `/etc/environment` but creating a file with the file name ending in `.sh` in `/etc/profile.d/`. The `/etc/profile` script and all scripts in `/etc/profile.d` are the global equivalent of each user's personal `~/.profile` and executed as regular shell scripts by all shells during their initialization.

---

**More detail:**

- `/etc/environment` is a system-wide configuration file, which means it is used by all users. It is owned by `root` though, so you need to be an admin user and use `sudo` to modify it.
- `~/.profile` is one of your own user's personal shell initialization scripts. Every user has one and can edit their file without affecting others.
- `/etc/profile` and `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` are the global initialization scripts that are equivalent to `~/.profile` for each user. The global scripts get executed before the user-specific scripts though; and the main `/etc/profile` executes all the `*.sh` scripts in `/etc/profile.d/` just before it exits.

---

- The `/etc/environment` file normally contains only this line:

  ```
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
  ```

  It sets the `PATH` variable for all users on the system to this default value, which should not be changed in a major way. At least you should not remove any of the important paths like `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin` from it.

  This file is read as one of the first configuration files by every shell of every user. Note that it is *not a shell script*. It is just a configuration file that gets parsed somehow and that may only contain environment variable assignments!
- The `~/.profile` file can contain many things, by default it contains amongst other stuff a check whether a `~/bin` directory exists and adds that to the user's existing `PATH` variable, like this (on older Ubuntu releases prior to 16.04 -- which adds it unconditionally -- and on 18.04, which also adds "~/.local/bin"):

  ```
  # set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
  if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
      PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
  fi
  ```

  You see that the old value of `PATH` gets reused here and the new path is only appended to the beginning instead of overwriting everything. When you manually want to add new paths, you should also always keep the old `$PATH` value somewhere in the new string.

  This initialization script is read only by the shells of the user to which it belongs, but there's another condition:

  ```
  # ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
  # This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
  # exists.
  ```

  So if you use the default Bash shell, you should make sure that you don't have a `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` if you want the changes in `~/.profile` to have an effect for your user.

---

For a full understanding on Environment Variables see:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

---

Related question: [difference between bash.bashrc and /etc/environment file](https://askubuntu.com/q/150789/367990)

Comment: Nowadays `~/.profile` does not check for the existence of `~/bin`, but it simply has the line: `PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Define "nowadays", please? I'm running 16.04 and that's how it looks there.

Comment: `/etc/skel/.profile` in 16.04 has the line I mentioned. You apparently created your user in a previous release.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks for the info -- until [about five minutes ago](https://askubuntu.com/posts/866240/revisions), I thought the default `~/.profile` still had this too, but you're right -- `/etc/skel/.profile` doesn't have it on my upgraded 16.04 system (and a user account created when installing 16.04 on another machine doesn't have it in their `.profile`).

Comment: "...executed as regular shell scripts by all shells during their initialization." I think this is misleading. Might suggest (to some) that simply opening a non-login terminal shell from the GUI desktop will execute /etc/profile, which it won't. https://askubuntu.com/questions/155865/what-are-login-and-non-login-shells

Comment: Beware not everything is an interactive shell so some things will not load any `.profile` or `.bashrc` e.g https://stackoverflow.com/a/18665363/516748

Comment: "So if you use the default Bash shell, you should make sure that you don't have a ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login if you want the changes in ~/.profile to have an effect for your user." - I'd argue that probably a better solution that deleting .bash_profile and .bash_login is to make use of those instead of .profile.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you wouldn't edit and extend `/etc/environment`? It seems made for the job...

Comment: Any thoughts on how the files in `/etc/default/*` factor in? The order of processing of all these ('etc/environment`, `/etc/default/*`, `/etc/profile`, `etc/profile.d/*`) is one aspect I'm interested in.

Comment: @cueedee https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/bash.1.html#invocation The INVOCATION section of the Bash manpage describes exactly which file is read when and under what conditions. Generally `/etc` before the equivalent user files. `*.d/` files are usually sourced explicitly from their respective base file and not by Bash directly. Whether bashrc and profile are read at all depends on whether Bash is invoked as interactive and/or login shell or not.

Comment: @ByteCommander, while that link covers a great deal of the invocation sequence for a `bash` shell, it has no mention of where the evaluation of the (shell-agnostic) `/etc/environment` and `/etc/default/locale` fit in, or in what order.

Comment: @cueedee I'm not fully sure, but I believe those other files you mention are read by PAM during the login of a user, not by any mechanism included in plain Bash. Can't tell you which order exactly though. To search references to those files, I tried reading through e.g. `grep -sRF /etc/default/locale /etc`.

Answer (score 47):

> This answer is mainly about **the order in which environment variables like `PATH` are assigned** when specified in different configuration files. I do also cover where you should usually set them, but the list below does not list files in the order that you should consider using them. For general information on setting `PATH` and other environment variables in Ubuntu, I also recommend reading [**EnvironmentVariables**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) and the other answers to this question.

The preferred place to set `PATH` depends on *which users* you need to set it for and *when and how* you want it to be set. Part of your decision will be whether you want an environment variable set for all users or on a per-user basis. If you're not sure, then I recommend setting it for just one user (e.g., your account) rather than systemwide.

As [AlexP says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866161/setting-path-variable-in-etc-environment-vs-profile#comment1339305_866161), the `PATH` environment variable will have the value it was *most recently assigned*. In practice, *most* of the time you set `PATH`, you include the *old* value of `PATH` in the new value, so that the previous entries are retained.

Thus, in practice, when `PATH` is set from multiple files, it usually contains the entries given in all the files. But that only happens because all files that set it, except the first one, usually reference the `PATH` variable itself, causing its old value to be included the new one.

Therefore, you are in effect asking for the order in which `PATH` settings in various files take effect.

Common, general-purpose places to set `PATH` are listed below in the order in which they take effect when a user logs in, ***not* in the order you should typically consider using them**. Each of the places listed below is a reasonable choice for setting `PATH` **in *some* situations**, but only a few are good choices most of the time.

<sup>In the list below, you'll see some directory names like `~/.profile`. In case you're unfamiliar with [tilde expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Tilde-Expansion), `~/` refers to the current user's home directory. I mainly use this syntax for compactness. It is supported in shell scripts, but *not* in PAM configuration files.</sup>

#### 1. For all users: `/etc/environment`

[PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) on Ubuntu causes environment variables listed in `/etc/environment` to be set, if that file exists, which by default it does. That's how environment variables for all users are most commonly set.

```
$ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

If you must set environment variables for *all* user accounts, rather than just your user account, then modifying that file is likely your best choice. I recommend backing it up first. One way to back up this file is to run:

```
sudo cp /etc/environment /etc/environment.orig
```

The `.orig` extension is not specifically required -- you can feel good about naming the backup file anything that's not confusing or already being used. (Besides `.orig`, `.old`, `.backup` and `.bak` are common.)

You can edit this file in any of the ways you might edit any other file as the root user (`sudoedit /etc/enviromnment`, `sudo nano -w /etc/environment`, `gksudo gedit /etc/environment`, etc.)

`/etc/environment` doesn't support including the old value of a variable automatically. But this is usually unnecessary, since most of the time you would set an environment variable for all users by editing `/etc/environment`, you would want that to be its initial value when the user logs in, anyway. The user could then change it as they like. Typically it is good for users to be able to do this.

#### 2. For all users: `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`

PAM reads environment variables for all users from `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`, specified with the same syntax as used in per-user `~/.pam_environment` files (see below).

When the same environment variable is set in both `/etc/environment` and `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`, the value in `pam_env.conf` is used -- even if that value is specified as `DEFAULT` rather than `OVERRIDE`.

However, when you supersede a line in `environment` with one in `pam_env.conf`, you can include the contents of the superseded value. See the section below on `.pam_environment` for details (since it uses the same syntax).

It's not usually necessary to edit `pam_env.conf` and **you should be very careful if you do**, since a *malformed* line will usually prevent all normal user accounts from logging in at all! For example, the default `pam_env.conf` contains the lines:

```
#PATH           DEFAULT=${HOME}/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin\
#:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin/X11:/usr/bin/X11
```

This is presented as one of several examples. One of the things it illustrates is how to split an assignment across multiple lines with `\`. Suppose you were to uncomment just the first line, but forgot to uncomment the second line:

```
PATH           DEFAULT=${HOME}/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin\
#:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin/X11:/usr/bin/X11
```

<sup>***Don't do this!***</sup>

I just tested that myself by accident, and it prevented any users from logging in successfully. To fix it, I had to boot in recovery mode and change it back. (Fortunately I did this on a virtual machine I use only for testing things, so it didn't cause me any trouble.)

#### 3. For one user: `.pam_environment` in the user's home directory

One of the ways to set an environment variable for a single user is for that user to edit (or create) `.pam_environment` in their home directory. Values set in this file supersede those set in the global `/etc/environment` file.

`.pam_environment` is not part of the skeleton of files that is copied into a user's home folder when the user account is initially created. However, if you create that file in your home directory, you can use it to set environment variables like `PATH`. Unlike `/etc/environment` (but like `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`), the per-user `.pam_environment` files do support expanding the old value of an environment variable into a new one. They are not shell scripts, however, and you must use a special syntax to achieve this, which differs somewhat from the syntax you would use in a file like `.profile`.

For example, if you had a `bin2` directory in your home directory that you wanted to add to the end of `PATH`, you could do that by adding this line to `.pam_environment`:

```
PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:/home/@{PAM_USER}/bin2
```

See [the `~/.pam_environment` subsection](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2BAH4-.2F.pam_environment) of [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) (from which the above example is closely adapted), [`man pam_env`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/pam_env.8.html), and [`man pam_env.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/pam_env.conf.5.html) for further details.

Although this was once touted as the preferred way for Ubuntu users to change or add environment variables and is still considered a reasonable and acceptable choice, **you should be careful when editing `.pam_environment`**. Like edits to the systemwide `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` (see above), a malformed line in a user's `.pam_environment` file will prevent logins from succeeding. (I have tested this -- on purpose this time.) For information about how [the recommendations](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables) have [evolved](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables?action=info), see [Gunnar Hjalmarsson](https://askubuntu.com/users/159370/gunnar-hjalmarsson)'s [comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866161/setting-path-variable-in-etc-environment-vs-profile/866240#comment1339715_866240) [below](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866161/setting-path-variable-in-etc-environment-vs-profile/866240#comment1339717_866240) and [this `ubuntu-devel` discussion](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2013-December/037899.html).

Such a mistake is much less serious, *in general*, than a malformed line in `pam_env.conf`, because it affects only one user. However, in the case of a desktop Ubuntu system with only one user account that allows logins, such a mistake while editing `.pam_environment` will be just as bad as a mistake editing `pam_env.conf` -- if you're not already logged in, you won't be able to fix it without booting in recovery mode (or from a live USB, etc.).

(If you do have other user accounts, then you can log in as another user and fix the problem. Even if they're not an administrator and cannot `sudo` to root, they can still run `su your-account` and be prompted to enter your (not their) password. The *guest* account, however, cannot do this, as it is prohibited from using `su` to take on the identity of another user.)

#### 4. For all users: `/etc/profile` and files inside `/etc/profile.d/`

Bourne-compatible shells (including `bash`, the default user shell in Ubuntu) run the commands in `/etc/profile` when invoked as a login shell.

Ubuntu's `/etc/profile` ends with:

```bsh
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

This causes the commands in any file in the `/etc/profile.d/` directory whose name ends in `.sh` to be run as well.

Most display managers cause the commands in `/etc/profile` (and thus files in `/etc/profile.d`) to be run for graphical logins too. However, **not all do, and that's a significant argument in favor of using the facilities provided by PAM instead** (see above) -- unless there will never be any graphical logins to this system, which might be the case, for example, if it's a server with no GUI installed.

It's traditional to set systemwide environment variables in `/etc/profile`, but this is often not the best choice anymore. If you cannot set an environment variable in `/etc/environment`, and you must set it for all users, then it's probably better to make a new file in `/etc/profile.d/` than to edit `/etc/profile` itself. One reason for this is that, when Ubuntu is upgraded, there may be a new default `/etc/profile` file. Depending on how you perform the upgrade, either the old file (with your changes) will be kept, foregoing that particular updated configuration file, or you will be prompted to handle the situation.

*When the same environment variable is set in both `/etc/profile` and one or more files in `/etc/profile.d`, which is performed last?* This depends on whether the commands in `/etc/profile` that set them appear before or after the files in `profile.d` have been sourced (by the code I've quoted above). Commands in `/etc/profile` are executed in the order they appear.

`/etc/profile` is a shell script, and **its syntax is *not* the same as that of the PAM configuration files discussed above**. Its syntax is the same as the syntax for the per-user `~/.profile` file (see below).

If you need to write code that *decides* whether or not to add a particular directory to `PATH` (and to do so for all users), you won't be able to use `/etc/environment` or `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` to do that. This is perhaps the main situation where it is better to to use `/etc/profile` or `/etc/profile.d/` instead.

#### 5. For one user: `.bash_profile` in the user's home directory

If a user has `~/.bash_profile`, bash uses it instead of `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_login` (see below). You should not usually have a `.bash_profile` in your home directory.

<sup>If you do, it usually ought to contain a command to source `~/.profile` (e.g., `. "$HOME/.profile"`). Otherwise, the contents of the per-user `.profile` file aren't run at all.</sup>

#### 6. For one user: `.bash_login` in the user's home directory

If a user has `~/.bash_login`, bash uses it instead of `~/.profile` (see below), unless `~/.bash_profile` exists, in which case neither of the others will be used unless sourced from `~/.bash_login.

As with `.bash_profile`, you should not usually have a `.bash_login` file in your home directory.

#### 7. For one user: `.profile` in the user's home directory.

When a Bourne-style shell is run as a login shell, it runs the commands in `/etc/profile` (which typically includes commands that cause the commands in files in `/etc/profile.d/` to be run -- see above). After that, it runs the commands in `.profile` in the user's home directory. This file is separate for every user. (Bash actually runs `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` instead if they exist -- but, for users on an Ubuntu system, those files rarely should or do exist. For details, see above and [6.2 Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files) in [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/).)

`~/.profile` is thus the main place for user to put commands that run when they log on. It is the traditional place for you to set your `PATH`, but since Ubuntu has the pam_env module and supports `~/.pam_environment`, you should consider using that.

As with `/etc/profile`, not all display managers run this file for graphical logins, though most do. **This is a reason to prefer `~/.pam_environment` for setting environment variables** (much as one may prefer `/etc/environment` to `/etc/profile`).

You can expand environment variables, including `PATH` itself, when you set `PATH` in `.pam_environment` (see above). However, if you need to set `PATH` in a more sophisticated way, you might have to use your `.profile` instead. In particular, if you want to check if a directory exists every time a user logs in and only add it to `PATH` if it does, then you won't be able to use your `.pam_environment` file to add that directory to your `PATH`.

For example, the default per-user `.profile` file on Ubuntu *used to* end with:

```bsh
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

<sup>See [Gunnar Hjalmarsson](https://askubuntu.com/users/159370/gunnar-hjalmarsson)'s [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866161/setting-path-variable-in-etc-environment-vs-profile#comment1339354_866169) on [Byte Commander's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/866169/22949) for details.</sup>

This checks if you have a `bin` subdirectory of your home directory. If so,  it adds that subdirectory to the beginning of your `PATH`.

#### *That list omits some possibilities.*

There are other ways environment variables are set when users log in that depend more heavily on the type of login. For example, you may occasionally have environment variables that get set just for graphical logins or just for SSH-based remote logins. The list above does not cover such cases.

I've left out a few files where people sometimes define environment variables, like `~/.bashrc` and `/etc/bash.bashrc`, because they are not generally recommended places to set `PATH` and it is rare that you should actually use them for this purpose. If you use these files to add directories to `PATH`, then they will sometimes be added many times and is very confusing when you examine `$PATH`. (In extreme cases this may slow things down, but usually it's just a matter of keeping everything clean and understandable.)

Since `bash` is Ubuntu's default login shell for users, and most users use it or some other POSIX-compatible shell, I've omitted information about how environment variables are set in other, non-Bourne-style shells such as `tcsh`.

Comment: \[comment #1 of 2] Thanks for this extensive description! (I did a minor edit.) However, I have doubts as regards the recommended way(s). A few years ago [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) mentioned `/etc/environment`/`~/.pam_environment` as **the** recommended files. After having [consulted with the developers](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2013-December/037899.html) I changed it to be neutral between PAM and `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`/`~/.profile`, and I still tend to look at it that way.

Comment: \[comment #2 of 2] You mentioned a couple of arguments in favor of PAM. Important arguments in favor of `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`/`~/.profile` are that the syntax is simpler and that lightdm/gdm are forgiving in case of errors (not even syntax errors prevent you to log in, but just result in warning messages).

Comment: When you say `pam_env.so`, did you mean `pam_env.conf`?

Comment: @JohanBoulé Yes, I did mean `pam_env.conf`. Thanks! I've edited to fix it.

Comment: In #4, shouldn't "Ubuntu's `/etc/profile.d` ends with:" be just "Ubuntu's `/etc/profile` ends with:"?

Comment: @DKBose Yes, definitely. Thanks! (Fixed.)

Comment: Any thoughts on how the files in `/etc/default/*` factor in?

Answer (score 5):

**/etc/environment** file is not a script file you can't use export there and it doesn't support variable expansion of the type $HOME, just simplevariable=value pairs. So to use that file, you'd need to simply append your path to the existing definition , is specifically meant for system-wide environment variable settings. one per line. Specifically, this file stores the system-wide locale and path settings.

**~/.profile** - This file gets executed whenever a bash shell is executed,is usually the recommended one for environment variables,however it has the disadvantage of only being invoked by login shells, so in order to get it to take effect you will need to log out and back in - or at least, start a new login shell.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred place to set *environmental variables* depends on several things:

1. Are you the only one using the computer:

   - In this case the best place to set it would be in the `/etc/environment` since there is no danger of _unauthorized access.
2. If the system is used by many

   - If the *variables* should be accessed by all then the location would be `/etc/environment`, but
   - if *individual users* should have selected access to them then *each should set theirs in the `~/.profile`* pertaining to each user of the system since it's located in each users home directory.

The system will read `/etc/environment` before reading `~/.profile`. No *concatenation* occurs and like *Alex P* said the last *assignment* to path prevails.

For more detailed look at the factors that determine how `~/.profile` and `/etc/environment` play out with other such locations go [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463462/sequence-of-scripts-sourced-upon-login), as these factors will influence how you use these locations.

Answer (score 0):

bash reads these files, but zsh does not:

1. system-wide

   `/etc/profile` - It's not a good idea to edit it directly.
   `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` - sourced by `/etc/profile`
2. session-wide

   `~/.profile`

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fprofile.d.2F.2A.sh

Answer (score -1):

Check your `/etc/environment` file. It should contain only literal path i.e it should not contain something like "`$PATH=$PATH:<any_path_you_want_to_add>`".

That will cause an error into your system and make you stuck in the login loop.