# Wrong logname at login in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: bash, login, 21.10

I upgraded my Ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10 yesterday and am running into serious problems after rebooting.

## Troubles with graphical drivers (solved)

This is solved, but maybe I broke something by solving this problem ? Ubuntu stuck during boot and the desktop was never showing. I restarted in rescue mode, updated grub to add "nomodeset" and did some reinstallations + reconfigurations :

```
apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
dpkg-reconfigure gdm3 ubuntu-session xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
dpkg-reconfigure ubuntu-session xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
apt reinstall gdm3 gnome-shell yaru-theme-gnome-shell
```

I then updated grub2 after reboot to make the "nomodeset" permanent.

## Identity problem

After finally reaching my desktop, everything first seemed reset to default and my files disappeared from Desktop... until I opened a terminal and saw errors related to filesystem rights on /root/ (?!). After digging a little I came to understand that in bash my HOME environment variable is set to /root, that my LOGNAME is "root"... basically **bash** thinks that I'm root while **system/C** programs still recognize me correctly as my actual user. The desktop shown is /root/Desktop and not my user desktop, and so on. My files are still present on disk.

Testing some bash variables :

```bsh
amael@laptop:~$ echo $LOGNAME
root
amael@laptop:~$ echo $USER
root
amael@laptop:~$ echo $HOME
/root
amael@laptop:~$ echo ~
/root
amael@laptop:~ echo $MAIL
/var/mail/root
```

Note that the prompt shows the correct username whereas  the default folder when opening the terminal is the wrong : $HOME = /root.

Non-shell commands show the correct username :

```bsh
amael@laptop:~$ whoami
amael
amael@laptop:~$ logname
amael
amael@laptop:~$ id
uid=1000(amael) gid=136(vboxusers) groupes=136(vboxusers),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),120(lpadmin),131(lxd),132(sambashare),998(docker)
```

My /etc/passwd file seems unchanged and correct :

```
amael@laptop:~$ egrep "^root|amael" /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
amael:x:1000:136:Amael,,,:/home/amael:/bin/bash
amael@laptop:~$
```

My disks appear mounted in *rw* mode :

```bsh
amael@laptop:~$ ls -al /home
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  5 systemd-coredump systemd-coredump  4096 juil. 30  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root             root              4096 juil. 30  2020 ..
drwxr-xr-x 59 amael            vboxusers         4096 nov.  21 10:15 amael
drwx------  2 root             root             16384 juil. 30  2020 lost+found
amael@laptop:~$ mount | grep mapper
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-home on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
```

What can explain this ? I guess a full reinstallation can solve this but it would be nice not to have to do this.

Thanks for your feedback !

Comment: Just thinking... Some user startup ("profile") scripts may have been corrupted.

Comment: Well, the easiest answer is often the best. I had already checked most of profile scripts and went one again after reading your answer. This time I was successfull : the file /et/environment was containing a dozen of variables including HOME, LOGNAME, USER, MAIL... and all of them referring to root. Deleting all lines except PATH and LANG solved my issue, I can boot again to my profile and got everything back :) Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@FedonKadifeli was right : my /etc/environment file was somehow filled with many variables that should not be there. Deleting uncommon lines solved my problem !

I compared my file to a live-USB version and also checked here for reference about what should be in this file :  [Setting PATH variable in /etc/environment vs .profile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866161/setting-path-variable-in-etc-environment-vs-profile)

Problem solved.