# Referring to an existing environment variable in another

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Let's say I have an environment variable named `JAVA_HOME`, defined in `/etc/environment` file. I need to append a new value `JAVA_HOME/bin` in the `PATH` variable. Consider the following,

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/apps/jdk1.8.10_1
PATH=/bin/something/:/bin/bash/something:/usr/apps/jdk1.8.10_1/bin
```

Now if you look at it, if I could replace `/usr/apps/jdk1.8.10_1/bin`, with something like below, it would be more convenient.

```
PATH=/bin/something/:/bin/bash/something:JAVA_HOME/bin
```

How could I do that? Is it `%JAVA_HOME%/bin`?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/78856/referencing-environment-variables-in-etc-environment

Comment: @souravc- Thank you for the corrections in encoding. (y)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that in `/etc/environment`. It's not a script file, and variable expansion does not work there.

To modify `PATH` system wide, a file with a `.sh` extension in the `/etc/profile.d` folder is a better method. It can be named `myvars.sh` or just about anything, as long as it has the `.sh` extension. In your case it might look something like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/apps/jdk1.8.10_1
PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

That way you keep the default `PATH` definition in `/etc/environment`, and modify it in your own file.

Please see the [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) page for reference.

Comment: Thank you @Gunnar Hjalmarsson.. The exact answer I was looking for. I was thinking it is possible to refer to existing variables in `/etc/environment`.

Answer (score 2):

Referring to a variable is done by adding a `$` in `bash`. Check this entering:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/apps/jdk1.8.10_1
```

The command interpreter replaces the `$variable` by its value.

Your command would be:

```
PATH=/bin/something/:/bin/bash/something:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Don't use spaces, or your command won't work.

**Note:** The `%symbols%` around a variable name are Microsoft's style.

Comment: I downvoted your answer, since the OP asked about `/etc/environment`, which is not a script file. Please see my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the points mentioned @Jos. I find them really helpful in general..