# Reset PATH variable from TTY command line

Tags: environment-variables

I was in the process of installing Java 11 on Ubuntu 16.04 and decided to reboot my computer.

Now, when trying to login to my user or the guest user, when I press enter, I get a black screen followed by the login screen. When logging on to the TTY terminal I get warnings that my PATH variable has no entries, for example, not even ls is available for use without typing in `/bin/ls`. Aside: I used TTY to clear my `.Xauthority` records.

This is what I've done so far.

- Reset the PATH variable using the command `$PATH=(getconf PATH)`, I used `/usr/bin/getconf` instead since it's not on the PATH!
- Run reboot in the TTY. This leads to my PATH not working again.

Due to this, I cannot login to Ubuntu at all. I think the best way to resolve this is to reset the PATH variable and protect it from any changes during runtime (so I can trace my steps back in my installation of Java and find where I may be messing up). How can I do this?

This are the files I touched before running into this:

- environment in `etc/`
- `java.sh` and `jdk.sh` files in `/etc/profile.d`

Answer (score 0):

The whole reason I had this problem was because of an entry in `/etc/environment`.

I had added PATH recursively:

```
PATH=$PATH:
```

and was then running

```
export PATH
```

This would result in a recursive PATH, which I assume would never resolve.

Clearing this change in etc/environment fixed my issue and I can run Ubuntu again. :)

Comment: Note that `/etc/environment` is a configuration file not a shell script - it doesn't support statements like `export`, or even parameter expansion. See for example [Referencing environment variables *in* /etc/environment?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78856/referencing-environment-variables-in-etc-environment)