# proxy is only working with GUI but not when I set through terminal with ~/.bashrc

Tags: command-line, networking, proxy, bashrc

I have read a lot of guides about setting a proxy for ubuntu. I can do it with the GUI in the network settings and it automatically starts using the proxy I specified and when I open firefox or chrome to check my ip it shows the proxy ip.

But I'm not able to get it working with terminal by editing the `~/.bashrc` file. I do it like this:

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

then add this at the end of the file

```
export HTTP_PROXY="my_proxy:my_port"
export HTTPS_PROXY="my_proxy:my_port"
export FTP_PROXY="my_proxy:my_port"
```

then I save the changes and run the command

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

But when I open the web browser my IP did not change, I also tried rebooting the system but the ip remains the same.

Comment: Your .bashrc only applies to your bash shells (and programs spawned from it), not to your GUI login session as a whole. Try adding the values to `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`

Comment: I got the same result

Comment: @glennjackman Do you where are the changes made manually with GUI stored?

Comment: The proxy settings in GUI and in the terminal are independent and complementary to each other. GUI programs use the settings you define in GUI; command-line tools like `wget` use the environment variables you define in the terminal. To use proxy both in GUI and on command line, you have to define both.

Comment: Have a look at https://askubuntu.com/q/78856/10127

Answer (score 0):

You can write and configure a script. I need to throw a reverse tunnel from the virtual machine (Windows 10) to a Linux VPS on Digital Ocean and then use it back to Win7. I will imitate a situation where Windows 10 is the customer's machine, and the Linux VPS is our server. On the VPS, I install and configure the RsocksTun server side: I install an apt install [proxy service provider](https://soax.com/) and get the git clone GitHub as the source. This is a clone that will read the data. In the end, you need to generate an SSL certificate and run the server side.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using small letters like this:

```
export http_proxy="my_proxy:my_port"         
export https_proxy="my_proxy:my_port"
```

if it still doesn't work put those in '/etc/environment'

If you are using apt install you may also edit '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf' put those in there:

```
 Acquire::http::Proxy "http://host:port/";                            
 Acquire::https::Proxy "http://host:port/";
```